# creating the file with the same name as input

Tags: c++, visual-c++, io

```
cout << "Enter your full name";
char* name ;

cin >> name;
  if( _mkdir("c:\\names") == 0 ) {
     cout << "directory successfully created";
  }  else {
       cout << "there was a problem creating a directory";
     }
```

Now i want to create a file **( a .txt file )** in the directory `names` with the same name as the name of the `user`. I mean the name which the user entered during `cin >> name;`.

How can i do this ?

`ofstream writeName( "c:/names/????);`  ----> PROBLEM

Comment: `char* name; cin >> name;` - Do you think you know what this do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::string` instead of `char*`. As it is your code has Undefined Behavior. Use `std::getline` instead of `>>`. With `>>` only the first whitespace-separated "word" is input. Then, compose the full path in a `std::string`. The standard string class supports concatenation, so this should be easy.

Say, if that string is `path`,

```
std::ofstream f( path.c_str() );
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text file by `fopen` ing the file or with `ofstream`.

But your way of taking input for `name` seems wrong. You didn't allocate space for `name`. Try using `malloc` or `new`

Answer (score 0):

The `char*` points to one char. Since it is not initialized it points to nirvana -> *undefined bahavior*.

You can try to use `char name[MAX_LENGTH_FOR_YOUR_NAME]`. It's better to use a `std::string name` here.